# Labelling the rows of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add a new attribute "LabelId" to my dataframe based on the following conditions: given the input dataframe DF, find the k `nlargest(k, velocity)` and for each value I would like add and substruc some ms e.g. 50 by  applying the `apply(lambda x: x - np.timedelta64( 50, 'ms' ) )` and `apply(lambda x:  x + np.timedelta64( 50, 'ms' ) )` and set the new attribute `LabelId` to 1 otherwise to 0.

Input DF: considering 2 largest values of the velocity column and adding 50 ms.

```
    eventTime,               velocity
1,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:050,  3
2,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:100,  4
3,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:150, 180
4,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:200,  2
5,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:250,  5
6,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:050,  3
7,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:100,  4
8,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:150, 70
9,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:200,  2
10, 2017-08-19T12:53:55:250,  5
```

Output DF:

```
    eventTime,               velocity, LabelId
1,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:050,  3,        0
2,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:100,  4,        1
3,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:150, 180,       1 
4,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:200,  2,        1
5,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:250,  5,        0
6,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:050,  3,        0
7,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:100,  4,        1
8,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:150, 70,        1
9,  2017-08-19T12:53:55:200,  2,        1
10, 2017-08-19T12:53:55:250,  5,        0
```

I have been using the above functions but I did not get the right results. 
Please, any suggestion would be very appreciated. 
Many Thanks,
Best Regards,
Carlo

Comment: Can you describe in a more human way what is the meaning of LabelId?  What does `1` mean and what does `0` mean in that column?

Comment: OK, sure. 0 means "Writing" and "1" means "Reading". But it is not clear to me how this matter to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need top `eventTime` by [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html), then add `Timedelta` and get max and minimal timestamp. Last create mask by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html), which is cast to integers `0` and `1`:

```
df['eventTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['eventTime'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f')

a = df.nlargest(2, 'velocity')['eventTime']
low = min(a) - pd.Timedelta(50, unit='ms')
high = max(a) + pd.Timedelta(50, unit='ms')

#low   2017-08-19 12:53:55.100
#high   2017-08-19 12:53:55.200

df['LabelId'] = df['eventTime'].between(low,high).astype(int)
print (df)
```

Returns

```
                 eventTime  velocity  LabelId
1  2017-08-19 12:53:55.050         3        0
2  2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1
3  2017-08-19 12:53:55.150       180        1
4  2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1
5  2017-08-19 12:53:55.250         5        0
6  2017-08-19 12:53:55.050         3        0
7  2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1
8  2017-08-19 12:53:55.150        70        1
9  2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1
10 2017-08-19 12:53:55.250         5        0
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. One question: there is any relationship between the number 2 used in nlargest and a1 and a2? In case i use 10 in nlargest, should I change anything? The reason of that is that I am getting only 0 when apply the df['LabelId'] = df['eventTime'].isin(a).astype(int).

Comment: @CarloAllocca - I think you need all values between max and minimal values with top timestamp, `+-50ms` ? I edit answer.

Comment: I am struggling to get the right results on my data. Basically I am getting 1 only between the min and the max and not in each section as you show above.  I am using a = df.nlargest(15, 'velocity')['eventTime']

Comment: @CarloAllocca - there is problem get `low` and `high` values?

Comment: The problem is that the DF get labelled as 1 only between the low and high. Only one section s(from_low, to_high). I would expect 15 sections.

Comment: Not sure if understand. Problem is in sample data for `nlargest = 2` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165565/discussion-between-carlo-allocca-and-jezrael).

Comment: The above solution provided works on the sample data. Thanks Jezrael.

Comment: What is happen?

Comment: Sorry Jezrael. It was my mistake.